SwiftUI Drag-and-Drop in the Same List
When implementing drag-and-drop within the same List in SwiftUI, you may notice that it doesn’t work as expected—no green visual indicator appears. However, if you drag an element over a target element in a different list, it works correctly. Why is this?
Why t1 can be dropped on t4, but not t2?
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("t1")
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider(object: "aaaa" as NSString)
                    }
                
                Text("t2")
                    .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
                        // Handle drop for t2
                        return true
                    }
            }
            
            List {
                Text("t3")
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider(object: "aaaa" as NSString)
                    }
                
                Text("t4")
                    .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
                        // Handle drop for t4
                        return true
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

